# Is it possible to install MicroK8s on Ubuntu core 18?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, microk8s

Ubuntu Core 18 has snap built in, when trying to install it I get the following error:

```
$ sudo snap install microk8s
error: snap "microk8s" requires classic confinement which is only available on
       classic systems
```

Comment: @user535733 I tried `--classic`  `--edge`  or specifying different releases. All leads to same error message. Please note that this is Ubuntu **Core**. Installing on ubuntu 18.04 server cloud image works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Core only supports strictly confined snaps.

Ubuntu Core does not support `--classic` snaps. That is why you are seeing the "classic" error on a Core system, but not on a Cloud system.

Here is an [excerpt from the relevant release announcement](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-snap-introducing-classic-confinement) (January 2017):

> With snapd 2.20, a new confinement policy is introduced: “classic”,
>   designed to cater for all your scripting and tooling needs. Snaps
>   declaring their confinement as “classic”, have access to the rest of
>   the system, as most legacy (debian packages for example) packaged apps
>   do, while still benefiting from the ci-integrated store model, with
>   automated updates, rollbacks to older versions, release channels, etc.
>
> This new “classic” confinement is only available when snapd is
>   installed on top of a traditional Linux distribution, as opposed to
>   Ubuntu Core systems.

Answer (score 3):

We are actively working on getting a strictly confined snap to allow MicroK8s to run on Ubuntu  Core. There is a branch where you could follow the progress https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/tree/feature/jdb%2Fstrict . For now, the builds go in the latest/edge/strict channel. You can try this with:

`sudo snap install microk8s --channel=latest/edge/strict`

In case something does not work as you'd wish, we would appreciate your feedback. A simple inspection report should be enough (`microk8s inspect`). Thank you.